# Добавление JScrollPanel к JTextArea

Tags: java, swing

Могу ли я добавить элемент JScrollpanel к JTextAreа, не используя panel, box и т.д? Если да, то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(50, 50, 100, 100);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
```

метод "setViewportView()" делает именно то что ты хотел
для удобства если ты используешь WindowBuildel Editor в всплывающем меню есть удобная функция "Surround with"

Answer (score 1):

Можно примерно так:

public class Example {

**JTextArea incoming;**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example example= new Example ();
    example.go();
}

public void go (){
    ......
    incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);
    incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    incoming.setEditable(false);
    **JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming) ;**
    qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

.........